# Fetching tweets from Twitter api

Tags: hashtag, twitterapi-python

How can I get more than 1000 tweets from the Twitter using api for free?
The free version Twitter api giving only access to tweet and delete on the Twitter account.

I used rapid api but I got only limited number of tweets.Is there any other way ?